# C less-than operator

Tags: c

Working on a project for class and come across this piece of code I am supposed to use.

What is the "LT" operator? I assume it's some sort of less-than device, but I've never seen anything like this in C before (I'm new), and my compiler keeps telling me it's undefined.

```
int indexSmallest (struct dyArray * v, int i, int j) { 
    /* return index of smallest element */
    if (LT(dyArrayGet(v, i), dyArrayGet(v, j)) 
        return i;
    return j;
}
```

I know I can do a `(compare(x, y) == -1)` to work around this, but wanted to try and keep the code given to me.

Comment: Its not an operator.  It is either a macro or a function.

Comment: Maybe you don't know this: "if (a)" is pretty much the same as "if (a != 0)".

Comment: Fortran IV (1966) had comparison operators `.LT.`, `.GT.`, `.LE.`, `.GE.`, `.NE.` and `.EQ.`, and these names have been used frequently since then.  Perl still uses `lt`, `gt`, `le`, `ge`, `ne` and `eq` to compare strings.  The shell `test` operator uses `-lt`, `-gt`, `-le`, `-ge`, `-ne` and `-eq` to compare numbers (in part because `>` and `<` are I/O redirection operators).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already noted, `LT` is not a standard piece of C.  It is most probably a macro, and if you're expected to use the code shown, you should have been given a definition of the macro, possibly in a header.

A possible implementation for it follows, assuming that the type returned by `dyArrayGet()` is a numeric type:

```
#define LT(lhs, rhs)  ((lhs) < (rhs))
```

I'm not convinced it is any benefit in this scenario.  It might provide some value for comparing strings, where the definition might be:

```
#define LT(lhs, rhs)  (strcmp(lhs, rhs) < 0)
```

It all depends on what the `dyArrayGet()` function returns.

Answer (score 2):

LT is not an operator. I suspect you think it is an operator, because you're not familiar with the if (a)-syntax. These code snippets are equivalent:

```
int i = 5;
if (i != 0)
  foo();

int i = 5;
if (i)
  foo();
```

LT could be a function or a macro.

Comment: Well, aside from picking apart the OP's use of the term "operator", you didn't really answer the question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, aside from being non-constructive, your comment was useless. The question was: 'What is the "LT" operator?', second sentence.

Comment: Yes, and you did not answer that question.